# What kind of solutions/libraries for creating shapes onClick onto an img or other elements in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for potentially already-made solutions/libraries for handling user clicks ontop of a div or img that will create shapes where the user clicked.

I'll also have to have the ability to drag the shapes around once it's created.

Would it be fine just using a drag n drop library and implement creating the shapes by myself? is there a library built for creating shapes at the spot where a user clicked? (also programmatically resizeable)